# Пунктуация в предложениях типа определение при перестановке

Tags: пунктуация

В конструкциях типа: "Какая прелесть - быть на высоте!", "Какое это чудо: летать в облаках" ставится тире или двоеточие?

Comment: Нет, вы что. Я не ставил дизлайк!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот что пишет Розенталь ([§ 5. 2. Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=92)):

Тире ставится между подлежащим и сказуемым, если оба они выражены неопределенной формой глагола (инфинитивом) или **если один из главных членов выражен формой именительного падежа существительного, а другой — неопределенной формой глагола**:

*Конечно, это большое **искусство** — **ждать*** (Л. Соболев).

Какая прелесть — быть на высоте! Какое это чудо — летать в облаках.

Answer (score 1):

(1)  ***Какая прелесть — быть на высоте!  (2) Какое это чудо — летать в облаках!***

Тире в первом предложении интонационное, во втором случае при наличии ***это*** ставится в обязательном порядке.

***Быть на высоте*** — подлежащее, (какая) прелесть — сказуемое (***какая*** — в роли усилительной восклицательной частицы, ***это*** — связка (во втором предложении).

**Инверсия** подлежащего и сказуемого, тире в этом случае авторское и ставится для подчеркнутого интонационного деления.

Розенталь  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=92#pp92

**Тире не ставится:**

6) если **сказуемое предшествует подлежащему**: Прекрасный человек Иван Иванович! (Г.); Славное место эта долина! (Л.); Живописный народ индийцы (Гонч.); Неплохой ученик этот мальчик.

Постановка тире в этом случае **подчеркивает интонационное деление** предложения на два состава: Славные люди — соседи мои! (П.); Удивительное дело сон (Т.); Психологический курьёз — моя мать (Ч.); Ловкая штучка — умишко человеческий (М. Г.);

Но (при инверсии и отсутствии паузы): ***Какое счастье сына обнимать!*** (Долм.)

Comment: *при наличии это ставится в обязательном порядке* - Откуда такое правило? Вы не ошиблись?

Comment: Эту конструкцию можно рассматривать как инверсию предложения с прямым порядком слов: Летать в облаках - это чудо. Тогда "это" является связкой, тире перед связкой ставится обязательно, Пауза сохраняется и при инверсии. Но эту конструкцию можно рассматривать и как простое предложение с пояснением: Какое это чудо — летать в облаках. Здесь "это" - подлежащее, чудо - сказуемое. Поясняющий инфинитив в этом случае обособляется с помощью тире. Исходя из этих вариантов, я предполагаю интонационное членение предложения с "это" обязательным, произнести эту фразу без паузы не представляется возможным.

Comment: *произнести эту фразу без паузы не представляется возможным* - то есть вы все-таки говорите об интонационном тире?! Оно никогда не является обязательным. И уж тем более ничего подобного нет у Р.

Comment: У Р. правило совершенно другое. Тира ставится перед "это", если "сказуемое" (второй член) с него начинается  ("Летать - это чудо"). Все. Никаких других правил про "это" в подобных примерах у Р. нет. А в отношении перестановки подлежащего и сказуемого местами... Ну не знаю... Спрошу на всяк пожарный, хотя тут все равно не спасет.

Comment: Я предполагаю интонационное ЧЛЕНЕНИЕ предложения с "это" обязательным. Во многих темах Розенталь подчеркивает связь между "это" и тире. Но если этот вариант  вам кажется неубедительным, то   объяснить  тире можно по второму варианту с поясняющим инфинитивом. Розенталь http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=110#pp1103. Несогласованное определение, выраженное неопределенной формой глагола (инфинитивом), перед которой можно поставить слова а именно, отделяется посредством тире:

Comment: Мне кажется неубедитьным прежде всего то, что вы называете сказумым первую часть предложения, а Р. говорит только о тире **перед это**.  Ну а то, что интонационное тире тем и отличается от синтаксического, что оно не является обязательным, думаю, вам не надо объяснять.

Comment: Я могу только выразить сожаление, что наши точки зрения не совпадают. Я думаю, что вы можете дать свой альтернативный ответ. Возможно, он будет более убедительным и автор примет именно его (кажется,  он легко меняет свои решения).

Comment: У меня нет "точки зрения".  Я всего лишь убедился, что правила под вашу формулировку не существует.

Answer (score 1):

***Какое это чудо — летать в облаках!***

Во втором ответе я объясняю, почему  тире  при наличии ***это*** ставится в обязательном порядке.

1) По правилам Розенталя тире мы напишем в следующем предложении: ***Летать в облаках — это такое чудо.***

А при инверсии (и при наличии ***это***) ставится тире?

Увы, Розенталь не привел нам такого примера (не успел, упустил, не посчитал нужным — мы не знаем). У него есть только пример без тире при отсутствии ***это***:

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=92#pp92

2. ...Но (при инверсии и отсутствии паузы): ***Какое счастье сына обнимать!*** (Долм.)

Тогда решим эту задачу по его другому правилу с поясняющим инфинитивом.

Розенталь http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=110#pp110

3. Несогласованное определение, выраженное неопределенной формой глагола (инфинитивом), перед которой можно поставить слова а именно, **отделяется посредством тире.**

2) Итак,  задача решена, тире поставлено, но уж очень хочется **объяснить его в рамках предыдущей темы.** Попробуем?

Для простоты возьмем предложение без местоимения *какой*:

***Летать в облаках — это чудо***. Обязательное тире ставим по правилам Розенталя. А теперь рассмотрим **два варианта с инверсией** (с тире и без тире).

(1) ***Это чудо — летать в облаках.*** (2) ***Это чудо летать в облаках.***

Предложение 1 воспринимается вполне корректно, а вот предложение 2 при отсутствии тире выглядит как **назывное словосочетание (инфинитив в роли определения).**

И отсюда делаем вывод: **Тире при инверсии и при наличии это поставить необходимо.**

**ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ (для чего нам нужно интонационное тире)**

Оказывается, у него не одна, а две функции: а) **смысловое выделение**; б) авторское подчеркивание. Таким образом, интонационное тире (по Розенталю) в его первой функции можно приравнять к грамматическому.

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=94#pp94

1. Тире ставится для указания места разделения простого предложения на словесные группы, чтобы **подчеркнуть либо уточнить смысловые отношения** между членами предложения, когда другими знаками препинания или порядком слов нужный смысл не может быть выражен. Ср.:

Такое тире, называемое **интонационным**, может отделять любую часть предложения: *К станции приближались пешеходы — с узлами, мешками, чемоданами* — однородные члены предложения относятся к сказуемому и имеют значение дополнения, а при отсутствии тире могли бы быть восприняты как несогласованные определения к подлежащему:

2. Тире, которое ставится между членами предложения для выражения **неожиданности или для обозначения логического ударения,** также имеет **интонационный** характер: И щуку бросили — в реку (Кр.); Через несколько минут загремели цепи, двери отворились, и вошёл — Швабрин (П.).

Answer (score 0):

Если есть или можно вставить слово "это" - нужно ставить тире.

*Какая (это) прелесть - быть на высоте!*

*Какое это чудо - летать в облаках.*