# Подлежащее и сказуемое, выраженные инфинитивами

Tags: грамматика

Где здесь подлежащее и сказуемое - и почему?
**Ломать -- не строить.**
**Курить -- здоровью вредить.**

А в этих предложениях?
**Унывать -- смерть.**
**Унывать -- это смерть.**
**Это унывать -- смерть.**

И наконец - предложение, с которого все и началось.

**Какое это чудо -- летать в облаках.**
Отсюда: [Пунктуация в предложениях типа определение при перестановке](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/454672)

Здесь первая половина декларируется сказуемым, а вторая - подлежащим, причем некоторыми (не всеми!) в довольно необычной трактовке: сказуемое - рема, подлежащее - тема. Что само по себе говорит о дискуссионности утверждения.

Мне это совершенно не очевидно. Я спрашивал на двух ресурсах, но внятного ответа не получил. То есть все в общем-то сошлись во мнении, что тире интонационное (то есть факультативное), а вот грамматический разбор пояснить не смогли. А ведь именно на нем строится вывод о факультативности тире.

Там еще диковатая, на мой взгляд, идея о некоем *интонационном*, но *обязательном* тире просматривается, но это уже другой разговор.